# How to extend row group header to column in SSRS reporting service?

Tags: reporting-services, report, row

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-UbK3bMZOUVk/T3XSXg3mJDI/AAAAAAAABBo/K7z0CQtD9Yw/s258/Extend_GroupHeader.png]

As shown above, this trapped me for a long time.

This is a matrix in SSRS 2008 (under Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1). 
I need to generate a simple report, which contains Client Name and the staff's name, hours in the period. 
The report in the left hand side of the red line is the row group with 2 groups in parent/child. 
In the right hand side of the group is the column group, grouped by period (date), which will display the hours from the database.

However, the restriction of the column group does not allow the Client Name (Row Group Header) to utilize the empty/blank space over the red line. 
Thus, if the Client Name is too long, it will goes to the second line.

I would like to know if there is anyway that I can utilize/extend the row to utilize the space under the column group, like the image shown below,

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PVBvAqD2yhc/T3XSY0s8INI/AAAAAAAABBw/DFu8-hOdcwM/s443/Extend_GroupHeader2.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't merge cells like this in in a matrix. If you can get rid of the column grouping then you've got options.

Methods to get rid of the column group would be to use either a subreport or place a tablix with a column group within your base tablix. This will probably require some rewriting of your queries.

Comment: I can't. The column group is needed to display other information. I tried many ways, can't extend the row group header to utilize it or like ignore that line not in the column group.

Comment: I gave a couple ideas for how you might do away with the column group.

Comment: Thanks. Tried everything I know, you're right, can't do that.